# Troubleshooting slurm e-mail settings

Tags: email, slurm

I am trying to setup a slurm installation and I have advanced towards the e-mail stage. So far I do not receive any mails. I have a working setup using `msmtp-mta` and `msmtp`. When I batch a script the slurmctld log shows

```
email msg to **@**: Slurm Job_id=73 Name=example_script.sh Began, Queued time 00:00:00
```

But I receive nothing. To troubleshoot the issue, I wrote a small script that does nothing but log calls:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="${HOME}/mail.log"

echo "Called with args" >> ${LOGFILE}
echo $* >> ${LOGFILE}

# exit 1
```

I saved it as `/usr/bin/slurm_mail` (ls -l: `-r-xr-xr-x 1 slurm slurm 109 Jan 27 14:00 /usr/bin/slurm_mail` ), expecting some kind of output and set the configuration accordingly:

```
> scontrol show config | grep MailProg
MailProg                = /usr/bin/slurm_mail
```

But I still get absolutely nothing, so the script is apparently (?) never executed, despite being present on all hosts (actually one host, running `slurmd` and `slurmctld`). Is there any way to debug this issue (I set `SlurmctldDebug` to `debug5` without getting any new information)?

Comment: On my Ubuntu installation the default slurm user does not have a home directory. Does `$HOME` point to a suitable directory?

Comment: I added it using `mkhomedir_helper slurm`. `passwd` shows `slurm:x:64030:64030::/home/slurm:/usr/sbin/nologin`.